# SVG paint-order with letter-spacing in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, firefox

In SVG the [paint-order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order) allows us to *"control the order in which the fill and stroke of text content and shapes are drawn"*, and it's quite useful to put the stroke behind the fill.

However, I just found that in Chrome, when changing the `letter-spacing` CSS property, instead of all strokes being painted behind all fills it seems that **each letter** is painted individually.

For instance, given this snippet:

```css
text {
  font-size: 60px;
  stroke: wheat;
  stroke-width: 10px;
  letter-spacing: -5px;
  paint-order: stroke;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="120">
  <text x="10" y="100">This is an example</text>
</svg>
```

This is how it looks like in Chrome:

[image]

While, in Firefox for instance, the result is what I'd expect:

[image]

Thus, before reporting a bug, I'd like to ask: is this behaviour really implementation-dependent (that is, each browser implements it the way they please) or is it specified somewhere in the SVG documentation?

Comment: The SVG 2 specification describes these individually. It does not say that letter-spacing turns off paint-order, but then again it doesn't say it does either. I'd say this is a Chrome bug though FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution: instead of adding a `stroke: wheat` to the text you can use a filter feMorphology with an `operator="dilate"`.

```css
text {
  font-size: 60px;
  letter-spacing: -5px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="120">
<filter id="outline">
<feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="expanded"
operator="dilate" radius="3"/>
<feFlood flood-color="wheat" result="color" />
<feComposite in ="color" in2="expanded" operator="in" />
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
  <text filter="url(#outline)" x="10" y="100">This is an example</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: The serious disadvantage of this approach is that the Morphology filter does not draw correct corners. Dilation always produces rectangular shapes there, an effect that will be more visible the larger the value is.

Comment: @ccprog this isn't a problem when using radius="3". At bigger values - yes it's a problem